# Conditional jump to memory address

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Is something like the following possible?

```
cmp $3, %rdi
jz (%r11)
```

> file.s:52: Error: operand type mismatch for `jz'

Or:

> Warning: indirect jmp without `*'

Or do you have to jump 'through' a label which can then do the `jmp %r11`. Or how does that work?

It seems there are at least a few things going on here, but one of them is:

- Giving a warning unless I change `jmp %r11` to `jmp *%r11` (why?)

Currently what I'm doing is the roundabout:

```
cmp $3, %rdi
jz fast_ret

fast_ret:
    jmp *%r11
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, [all the conditional jump instructions on x86 are immediate](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc); they take the destination address encoded directly into the instruction (as a displacement from the address of the jump instruction itself).  You can't conditionally jump to an address from a register or memory location.

You can do what you did, and jump to the desired jump instruction.  Or you can  reverse the test and jump around the register or indirect jump that you really want.

```
    cmp $3, %rdi
    jnz dont_go
    jmp *%r11
dont_go:
    // rest of your program
```

Your way has the advantage that no jump is taken in the "not equal" case, though branch prediction on modern processors shouldn't leave much difference between "taken" and "not taken".  My way has the advantage that neither case involves taking two jumps, and there isn't a jump to some relatively distant intermediate address that may be cold in cache.

Be careful of the difference between:

- `jmp %r11`: invalid syntax for AT&T, absolute jumps always take `*` prefix, see https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html#i386_002dVariations.
- `jmp *%r11`:  use the contents of `%r11` as the address to jump to.  You can think of it as doing `mov %r11, %rip`.
- `jmp *(%r11)`: indirect jump, fetch the destination address from the address which `%r11` contains.  You can think of it as doing `mov (%r11), %rip`.

Answer (score 3):

Nope it's not, assembly language can only do what machine code allows, see https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc and notice that they're all `jcc rel8/rel32` relative direct, not indirect.

You *could* `cmov` to select between addresses for `jmp *%reg` so it jumps to the next instruction by using something like this:

```
# possible, but not recommended
# %r11 holds a target address you might want to jump to
   lea    .Lfallthrough(%rip), %r10
   cmp     ...
   cmovne  %r11, %r10           # make the jump go to R11 if !=
   jmp    *%r10
.Lfallthrough:
```

Normally it's better to just conditionally jump to or over an indirect `jmp` or `ret` for an early out `ret`, or conditional indirect jump, if you can't easily make fallthrough one of your indirect-branch target possibilities.

If the indirect-branch predictor doesn't have a target-address prediction, the default is the next instruction, because it's possible to construct cases like this where one of the actual possibilities is there.

---

> Giving a warning unless I change jmp %r11 to jmp *%r11 (why?)

Because that's how AT&T syntax works.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html - *AT&T absolute (as opposed to PC relative) jump/call operands are prefixed by `*`*

This is necessary to disambiguate bare memory operands, and for consistency the decoration is expected with all indirect jumps / calls.

- `jmp foobar` (jump to that symbol, setting EIP/RIP=`foobar`)
- `jmp *foobar` (load a pointer into EIP/RIP from absolute address of symbol `foobar`)